# How to select a column that doesnt exist and increments numerically to the final row

Tags: postgresql

So this is a unique request.
Please understand I am limited to only making queries not creating new tables or new columns.

I have too create a query where i get all the classes within the school and give them a new identifier with a number made for simplicity e.g.

| SchoolNumber | Classname | Simple Identifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 179535 | 4a | 1 |
| 179535 | 4b | 2 |
| 179535 | 5a | 3 |
| 179535 | 5b | 4 |
| 179535 | 6a | 5 |
| 179535 | 6b | 6 |
| 478953 | 1a | 7 |
| 478953 | 2a | 8 |
| 478953 | 3a | 9 |
| 324598 | 1a | 10 |
| 324598 | 1b | 11 |
| 324598 | 1c | 12 |
| 324598 | 2a | 13 |
| 324598 | 2s | 14 |
| 324598 | 2c | 15 |

You get the Idea! How can I add a column with values incrementing without having to actually create a new column in the table since as I mentioned before my position does not allow me to create tables or columns or values

I came accross this on the internet

```
SELECT x1, x2, x1-x2 AS difference
FROM (VALUES
  (2,42),
  (13,7),
  (42,2)
)
  AS xoffsets(o1,o2)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT x+o1,x+o2  -- here we add the offsets above to x
  FROM generate_series(1,3) AS t(x)
) AS t(x1, x2)
ORDER BY x1, x2;
```

This query proves one can generate a number sequence. My question is how in my case since I don't understand what is happening here?

my basic query looks something like this for reference

```
select  distinct sch.schoolnumber, cl.classname, 'SI' as Simpleidentifier
from schools sch
join classschool cs on cs.schoolid = schools.id 
join classes cl on cn.id = cs.classid
```

Comment: `row_number()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER()` was specifically defined for a case like this one. It produces a simple number starting from 1.

For example:

```
select distinct
  sch.schoolnumber,
  cl.classname,
  row_number() over(order by sch.schoolnumber, cl.classname) as Simpleidentifier
from schools sch
join classschool cs on cs.schoolid = schools.id 
join classes cl on cn.id = cs.classid
```